# Symfony, I have an error 500 when I put my site into production on the host 1and1

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I am in the process of putting into production the first version of my Symfony 5 site and I have an error **500**. I have put a `.htaccess` file in /public. I am on the host 1&1.
For my `.htaccess` file I took this one: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/web/.htaccess

here's what I have in the last lines of logs file:

```
[2020-03-17T23:16:12.375704+01:00] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2020-03-18T00:23:05.456699+01:00] console.ERROR: Error thrown while running command "assets:install web". Message: "The target directory "web" does not exist." {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The target directory \"web\" does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\waloude\\vendor\\symfony\\framework-bundle\\Command\\AssetsInstallCommand.php:108)","command":"assets:install web","message":"The target directory \"web\" does not exist."} []
[2020-03-18T00:23:05.484563+01:00] console.DEBUG: Command "assets:install web" exited with code "1" {"command":"assets:install web","code":1} []
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: look at log file what says , or change the environment to "env" in .env file and tell us what the error is saying

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you cant run command assets:install web because the folder web does not exist.
created it.

Comment: Where i create the web folder ?